# How do I change the color of each character

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with some code. I need to change the colour of every succeeding letter as it is being typed into the input

```js
let p = document.querySelector("p");
let input = document.querySelector("input")

function randomColor() {
  let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  let g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  return "rgb(" + r + " ," + g + " ," + b + ")";
}

input.addEventListener('input',function(){
   p.innerText = input.value
   for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
     p[i].style.color = randomColor()
   }
})
```

```html
<input type="text" name="">
 <p></p>
```

My problem:
They are not all in different colours  eg:I type in hello, each letter should be in a different random colour *************************************************************** PLEASE HELP OUT

Comment: You can't individually style a single letter; it has to be wrapped in a style-able element, like a `<span>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use innerHTML and add a span with a random color to it every time you input. Also, to get the text you inserted you need to use the event object, something like this:

```js
let p = document.querySelector("p");
let input = document.querySelector("input")

function randomColor() {
  let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  let g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  return "rgb(" + r + " ," + g + " ," + b + ")";
}

input.addEventListener('input',function(e){
  // since e.data can be null when backspacing we remove the last span when that occurs:
  if (e.data === null){
    p.removeChild(p.lastChild)
  }
  else {
    p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML + "<span style='color:" + randomColor() + "'>" + e.data + "</span>"
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="text" name="">
 <p></p>
```

Comment: You are right about that, I'll add a handler for that.

Comment: I added a condition for that case, if you see any flaws please tell me.

Comment: There are additional edge-cases (Copy+Paste, deleting multiple characters via highlighting or CTRL+Backspace, etc), however I don't think those are your responsibility to account for. You've given OP more than enough to go on. :) +1